# Is there a good way to wrap multiple, similar data models (with a few unique properties) into one table in the database?

Tags: c#

Let's say I've got two data models that share a lot of the same properties, but have a few key differences. For example:

```
public class Tiger 
{
  public long Id;
  public string Color;
  public List<Animal> Prey;
}

public class Mouse
{
  public long Id;
  public string Color;
  public List<Animal> Predators;
}
```

I want to add both models to my database, but ideally I'd have just one table that represents all Animals (rather than a Mouse table, a Tiger table, etc.). However, I also want to be able to store the unique properties of each. I know one option is a base class that resembles the following:

```
public class Animal
{
  public long Id;
  public string Color;
  public SpeciesTypes Species;
  public List<Animal>? Predators;
  public List<Animal>? Prey;
}

public enum SpeciesTypes
{
  Mouse = 1;
  Tiger = 2;
}
```

However, if possible, I'd like to avoid having a bunch of nullable fields, in case I create more SpeciesTypes that have unique properties. To summarize, is there any way to avoid creating a table in my database for each species, while also minimizing the number of nullable fields? My intuition is that if I'm running into this problem, each species might be different enough to warrant being treated as a unique model.

Comment: Why do you need the whole table of tigers? What is going to be the difference between them?

Comment: Do you need to use these extra properties for relations, queries or data validation? there is always the possibility to store data as key/values or as a serialized blob, but it will affect how you can work with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the use of [interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) to allow you to leave yourself better opportunities to extend in the future.

For example say we have an innterface called `IAnimal`

```cs
public interface IAnimal
{
  long Id {get;set;}
  string Color {get;set;}
  SpeciesTypes Species;
}
```

We can *extend* that interface using `interface` inheritance.

So if we wanted to have a `Predator` we could implement an interface like this

```cs
public interface IPredator : IAnimal
{
    List<IAnimal> Prey {get; set;}
}
```

And maybe something that says the animal is hunted by some predators, so lets create `IPrey`

```cs
public interface IPrey: IAnimal
{
    List<IAnimal> Predators {get; set;}
}
```

With that we can store any kind of predator, prey, or neither in a single database, or list.

```cs
IPredator shark = new Shark();
IPrey tuna = new Tuna();

shark.Prey.Add(tuna);
tuna.Predators.Add(shark);

List<IAnimal> animals = {
    shark,
    tuna
};
```